# RVM set ruby default, when open new terminal erase the RVM setting, go back to system ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal, rvm, zsh

I just got a new MacBook Pro and tried to setup the RVM in the system. I installed RVM and set the default to

`➜ rvm list default`

Default Ruby (for new shells)

ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

My RVM version is

`➜ rvm --version`

rvm 1.16.8 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

I have put `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.` at the bottom of the **.bashrc_profile**.

When I open the new Terminal window, I have done `rvm default` every time to reset from system ruby to rvm installed ruby.

I have done 3 hours research and read more than 20 different blogs about this issue. And I still do not have a solution for this problem.

Comment: is `.bashrc_profile` `source`'d on Terminal startup?

Answer (score 7):

If RVM **is** working in the shell but just isn't using the preferred ruby as default, set it with the following for 1.9.3:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

If RVM **isn't** working, it's likely a login shell problem that RVM isn't loading:

Login shells (typically when a terminal window is opened in an X window manager) will use `.bash_profile` but interactive, non-login shells reference `.bashrc` (likely where the rvm shell code are loaded).

### Option 1

Cheap fix, symlink them:

`ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile`

### Option 2

Optionally, some terminals (e.g. gnome-terminal) offer settings to force login shells for each new terminal session too.

### Option 3

Create a `.bash_login` file with the following contents:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

(Bash will check for `~/.bash_profile`, then `~/.bash_login`, and finally `~/.profile`.)

See the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for additional detailed information.

Comment: Option1: I have .bashrc and .bash_profile existed and could not be linked. Option 2: it is Mac OS X 10.8, it is standard one, so it cannot be done.  Option 3: created the file, still did not work.  I think something is super strong override whatever I am doing. I bet there is an error somewhere in my setting or missing paths so the change cannot be done. Need more info for the next steps

Comment: @MMA Have you tried `rvm repair all` to see if maybe it can figure it out?

Comment: @MMA `ln -s` will fail if the symlink path (.bashrc in your case) already contains a file, folder or symlink.  **Backup the existing .bashrc** and then delete it and then try Option 1 again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a `.bashrc_profile` file. I think you mean to have this line in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

There are to things to check:

1. go to terminal emulator, preferences, and enable login shell, sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` instead of just switching, put `/bin/login` would not work,
2. one of `~/.bash*` files might be resetting `PATH`, comment out any `PATH=...` lines.

After it is done make sure to open a new terminal (make sure to close it before).

Answer (score 0):

Use this `$ source $(rvm 1.9.3 do rvm env --path)`  and specify the version you want to use everytime you open a terminal. After you put that in you don't need to open another one because it will default back. So if you want to use v. 2.2.1 `$ source $(rvm 2.2.1 do rvm env --path)`