# Why is terminal saying rails is not installed suddenly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems, rvm

I restarted my computer and upon logging back in I got this message in the terminal:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 27 05:18:03 on console
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/Amir/Developer/appname/Gemfile'.
```

When I tried to start my local host with rails s i got:

Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

Ruby --version:

```
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

Gem File:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
```

Comment: I think this is due to the default ruby set in rvm. make sure the default is the ruby yu want and the ruby that you have rails installed in. The messages is saying that there is a ruby version declared in the gemfile, which is probably not the version you want

Comment: rvm list default returned ruby-1.9.3-p374 in my gem file i have ruby 1.9.3. I recently listed that ruby~ in my gemfile though. but i bundle installed and everything was working prior to restart

Comment: type git --version.. what do you get?

Comment: oops i meant ruby version

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]

Comment: thats the only ruby you have installed?

Comment: sorry in the apps directory its ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]

Comment: where you do have rails installed? in 374 or 392?

Comment: sorry but how do i check that?

Comment: use rvm to switch between them and do `gem list rails`

Comment: rvm --default use 1.9.3-p374.....
Using /Users/Amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374
....gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.2.13, 3.2.11)
rails_autolink (1.1.0, 1.0.9)

Comment: Now it works thank you. Im not sure why it switched my ruby version when i restarted my computer

Comment: why do i have to type rvm default everytime i open a new window?

Comment: see if this works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719027/rvm-set-ruby-default-when-open-new-terminal-erase-the-rvm-setting-go-back-to-s

Comment: I ran into the same thing. Macs suck.

Answer (score 1):

Check your shell initialization files:

- for `bash` it is `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`
- for `zsh` it is `~/.zshrc`, `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zlogin`

remove any lines that start with `PATH=` and do not follow with `$PATH:...` - this basically breaks RVM, there is a bug for OH-MY-ZSH - because it adds hardcoded `PATH=...` to `~/.zshrc` => https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/1359

Comment: I type in: user$ ~/.bashrc
And it returns: -bash: /Users/user/.bashrc: Permission denied

Comment: `user$` - this is prompt, it is displayed to you when you run a shell. you meant to run: `cat ~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the `ruby '1.9.3'` is your gem. You can install ruby via rvm (i.e, `rvm install ruby-<version>`) and specify the default project version.